# pyenv: compiling a module

Tags: makefile, pyenv

I am new to pyenv, using it now so I can have both Python 3.7 (system / default) and Python 3.6.5 (for compatibility with TensorFlow which does not yet support 3.7).

I installed 3.6.5 using

```
pyenv install -v 3.6.5
```

The TensorFlow repo I wanted to use works fine on this.

This repo will be part of a larger project. This project includes another repo https://github.com/argman/EAST, which requires compilation of some C++ code in the lanms folder.

When I run make in lanms, I get:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [adaptor.so] Error 1
```

I tried things like

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared CC=clang" pyenv install -v 3.6.5
```

which I found by Googling, but so far nothing has worked.

Note: lanms/make works fine under Python 3.7.

This seems to be quite a simple thing for those who know. If anyone has an idea, please help. Thanks

Full output of make below:

```
Chandrachuds-MacBook-Pro:lanms Chandrachud$ make
find: -xtype: unknown primary or operator
c++ -o adaptor.so -I include  -std=c++11 -O3 -I/Users/Chandrachud/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -I/Users/Chandrachud/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/include/python3.6m -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L/Users/Chandrachud/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin -lpython3.6m -lintl -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -Wl,-stack_size,1000000 -framework CoreFoundation adaptor.cpp include/clipper/clipper.cpp --shared -fPIC
adaptor.cpp:53:1: warning: 'pybind11_init' is deprecated: PYBIND11_PLUGIN is deprecated, use PYBIND11_MODULE [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
PYBIND11_PLUGIN(adaptor) {
^
include/pybind11/common.h:232:20: note: expanded from macro 'PYBIND11_PLUGIN'
            return pybind11_init();                                            \
                   ^
adaptor.cpp:53:1: note: 'pybind11_init' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
include/pybind11/common.h:216:5: note: expanded from macro 'PYBIND11_PLUGIN'
    PYBIND11_DEPRECATED("PYBIND11_PLUGIN is deprecated, use PYBIND11_MODULE")  \
    ^
include/pybind11/common.h:80:54: note: expanded from macro 'PYBIND11_DEPRECATED'
#  define PYBIND11_DEPRECATED(reason) __attribute__((deprecated(reason)))
                                                     ^
1 warning generated.
include/clipper/clipper.cpp:3665:13: warning: unused variable 'firstLeft' [-Wunused-variable]
    OutRec* firstLeft = ParseFirstLeft(outRec->FirstLeft);
            ^
1 warning generated.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: -stack_size option can only be used when linking a main executable
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [adaptor.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main issues here:

1. find is using xtype rather than type, which is not supported on Mac. You should be able to change xtype to type in the Makefile. e.g:

   ```
   DEPS = lanms.h $(shell find include -type f)
   ```
2. This error:

   ```
   ld: -stack_size option can only be used when linking a main executable
   ```

   You're passing `-Wl,-stack_size,1000000` to clang, which tells it to make an executable with a larger stack. However, clang is only creating a `.so` file, which can't control how big the stack is.

   The reason `-Wl,-stack_size,1000000` is in there is because of this line:

   ```
   LDFLAGS = $(shell python3-config --ldflags)
   ```

   The reason why `python3-config --ldflags` does this is because of a recent bug in Python: https://bugs.python.org/issue34960

   So, you could wait until Python fixes this, or you could do a workaround: Run `python3-config --ldflags`. Paste the output into the LDFLAGS line, minus the `-Wl,-stack_size,1000000` part. Then, you should be able to build it.

Comment: Thanks, this works, really helpful.
Any idea about the PYBIND11 warnings and how to get rid of them?
Thanks

Comment: I figured out how to resolve the PYBIND11 warnings. Just followed the guide here: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/upgrade.html#deprecation-of-the-pybind11-plugin-macro

Comment: And finally, one more thing to note when using pyenv. If you get this error:
"Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6", 
please follow the solution here:
https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap/issues/88

Comment: @cbasavaraj Thanks for the extra hints. I am also struggling to get `argman/EAST` to work correctly. I have the "Fatal Python error" you mentioned above, and tried to solve it by using `env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install -v 3.6.5` but I still get the fatal error. Do you have any other tips? I also get the fatal error when in a conda environment, and know it is something to do with multiple Python versions and the `adapter.so` file, but no idea what/how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, it's been a while since I worked on that project. But everything worked fine with the solution on that link. Why are you typing "env"? I don't use conda so no idea about that. But start with PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS=...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone reads this with a similar problem, here is the relevant section of the Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS0 = $(shell python3-config --ldflags) 

UNAME = $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    LDSTACK = -Wl,-stack_size,1000000
    LDFLAGS = $(filter-out $(LDSTACK), $(LDFLAGS0))
    DEPS = lanms.h $(shell find include -type f)
else
    LDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS0)
    DEPS = lanms.h $(shell find include -xtype f)
endif
```